# How can i keep rewriting to text file to add text?

Tags: c#, winforms

In top of form1 i did:

```
StreamWriter w;
```

In the constructor i did:

```
w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt");
```

Now i have a checkbox that enable a button:

```
if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                if (marklightnings == true)
                {
                    myTrackPanelss1.panel1.Enabled = true;
                    myTrackPanelss1.panel1.Visible = true;
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
```

Now in the button1 click event i write to the text file:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w.WriteLine("test");
            w.Close();
        }
```

What i want to do is that each time i check the checkbox it will open the text file for writing but not to create a new text file but to use the same exist text file and just add a text to it.

Its not a settings file but it is a text file i need later to read the text from it.

What i need is that when the button1 is enabled i will be able to click on it ant it will add text to the text file each click.
So i did w.Close();
But then it cant be add more text to be written. If i will make new instance for w it will create new empty text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt", true);
```

**Or**:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"d:\test.txt"))
    {
        w.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `File.AppendAllText`. Note that you don't need to call `Close` in your second snippet - the `using` statement will dispose of the writer for you.